# 6 numbered balls drawn from a bin of 44 balls. Remaining 38 balls distributed into 7 groups. Why 7?

Tags: combinatorics

***Q*** *The Aopslandia lottery consists of randomly drawing 6 balls (without regard to order) from a bin of 44 balls numbered 1 through 44. A group of citizens is concerned that the lottery may be rigged, because they have noticed that, historically, over 50% of the drawings have resulted in at least one pair of consecutive numbered balls being drawn. Should these citizens be concerned?*

***A*** *Let's compute the probability that a drawing has at least one pair of consecutively numbered balls. "At least" usually means either tricky casework or PIE, so let's count the complement instead: the probability that a drawing has no pair of consecutively numbered balls.*

*If we draw 6 balls, no two of which are consecutive, then the remaining 38 (undrawn) balls are distributed into 7 groups: the balls less than the smallest drawn ball, the balls between the two smallest drawn balls, and so on.*

My question is: why does it state that the balls are distributed into 7 groups? If the smallest number is drawn, then there aren't 7 groups, but 6 groups because there are no balls less than the smallest ball drawn. If the largest number is also drawn, then there'd be only 5 groups. So why does this work? Why aren't they taken into account?

Comment: You might have an empty group :-)

Comment: groups can be empty, they say the balls are distributed but not that all the groups need to contain at least one ball.

Comment: Weird, but yes, that would make sense.

Comment: You have a good point here, actually, because while the first and last group may be empty, presumably the point of the "seven groups" is that none of the other five groups may be empty. One may hope the text after this somehow takes those things into account.

Comment: @DavidK "To simplify things, imagine that there's a extra undrawn ball labeled 0 and an extra undrawn ball labeled 45. This means that there are 40 undrawn balls in 7 groups, and each of the groups must be nonempty. In other words, we have a 1-1 correspondence"  - This is the rest of the text.

Comment: That's how they dealt with it, then. Now there are seven groups, each with at least one ball. Anywway, I get about $46.2\%$ for the probability that there are no two consecutive balls drawn.

Comment: Even though that's how they dealt with it, it just didn't click. Got hung up too much on the paragraph that came before it. And yes, that's correct, the answer is 46.2% ;-)

Comment: One of the tricky things about reading math textbooks can be the question of whether it's time to pause reading and try to work out the truth of what has been said so far, or to keep reading because the explanation _might_ be in the next paragraph. Sometimes it's really hard to tell which one the author expected you to do.